# Excel Locked source file

Tags: excel

I have an excel doc that is full of data called source.xlsm. I have a number of other Excel docs (lets call one myfile.xlsm) that link to the data in source.xlsm. I linked to it via Data > GetData > FromFile > FromWorkbook then choosing the relevant table or sheet. All of the files are on a shared NAS drive. If both myfile.xlsm and source.xlsm are open on the same computer, all is right with the world. I can open, update, save as I choose with one or both of them open. However, if I open source.xlsm on one computer and myfile.xlsm is open on another computer, I cannot save source.xslm. It says it is being used by another user. It is not open anywhere, just being linked to for its data. If they're both on the same computer, then they're both fine to save at the same time. Is there a way around this as I want user to be able to open the various myfile.xlsm but I also want to be able to update the source.xlsm at the same time. Nobody else need open source.xlsm, just continue to use workbooks the link to it. I though that should be possible as the other user hasnt opened the file and the link is passive so the source file should not be locked?

Comment: Notionally, when the users open the referencing books, they only need to update the links (not open the source book). In which case, you could still edit the source. Of course, the changes won't be automatically updated to the users (until they close and reopen or manually update). To solve that, you could put some vba in the referencing books, to automatically update links (periodically or relevant-event-based).

Comment: But that’s not what’s happening. When a user on another computer opens the referencing workbook, the source on my computer becomes locked for editing. I can open it and I don’t get any warning. But when I try and save it I am told it is locked for editing.

Comment: Suspect then, that that's what you should seek to remove from the equation first. Simple testing excel external links should reveal the file doesn't need to open.

Comment: Indeed. User opens the reference file. Source file kept close. Reference file updates and works as expected. 
If another user opens the source file whilst the reference file is open there is no warning about read only. However the source file cannot be saved until the reference file is closed. Once it is closed, the source file can be saved without reopening it.